# PhpStorm incorrectly percieves the Event constructor to not to have any arguments

Tags: javascript, events, constructor, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

The [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) constructor accepts a `typeArg` as its first argument representing the name of the event.

```
class MyEvent extends Event {
   constructor(type, myData) {
      super(type); // <-- JetBrains PhpStorm complains: Invalid number of arguments, expected 0 
      //   ^^^^^^
   }
}
```

When invoking the constructor via `super()`, JetBrains PhpStorm complains:

> *Invalid number of arguments, expected 0*

While it should expect not only a `typeArg`, but there can also be an optional `eventInit`! So, why is this and how to resolve the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue, [WEB-40312](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40312) is fixed in upcoming PhpStorm 2020.1

Comment: I've just got the PhpStorm 2020.1 _(Build #PS-201.6668.153, built on April 13, 2020)_, and the issue is fixed, thanks :)